# Error reading session data when try "Session::instance();" in Kohana

Tags: session, kohana, kohana-3

On localhost everything good, but on deploy there is an error "**Error reading session data**" when I try invoke Session::instance(). Where is my mistake?
Maybe it's server problem or Kohana bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post your session.php?  Have you set your encryption key if you're using the encrypt option?  What driver are you using to store the session (file, cookie, database)?

Comment: I don't use encryption. The store for session is native (cookie). Problem solved by adding checking to session_start in kohana class. if ($_SESSION) session_start(); But good is it? I don't know...

Answer (score 2):

In my case, its a server problem. I had similar problem yesterday, and this how i solve it.

- first, set error handling to false (on bootstrap.php, set error => false) for better diagnose
- refresh again your browser. mine had error writing on C:\xampp\tmp. It turns out my "tmp" folder was missing (i dont know why, probably misdeleting due bad mouse habit)
- create tmp folder, done :)

btw, i'm using 'native' as kohana-session handler.
For xampp, you may check on xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf for "SetEnv TMP {your tmp dir here}". Other LAMP-stack may vary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the database (or ORM) for sessions then "Error reading session data" usually means that Kohana can't connect to the database. Check that you can connect to the database.

If you are using files for sessions then check the the folder where PHP writes sessions is writable.

Comment: I don't use encryption. The store for session is native (cookie). Problem solved by adding checking to session_start in kohana class. if ($_SESSION) session_start(); But good is it? I don't know..

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in session 'native' kohana 3.3. I got the error reading session data and broken data or something. When I check any data from `$_SESSION` array e.g. `echo $_SESSION['x']` there was that value I needed, so why this told me about error reading?

The error appears on line: `$session = Session::instance();`
I tried many solutions (php.ini, for example) without success.
My first solution was:

```
try{
$session = Session::instance();
}
catch (Exception $e){//do sth. eg. restrt sesion etc..}
```

But this was bad solution because few months later the problem back to me on another server.
I got the message Database_Exception [ 1030 ]: Got error 28 from storage engine...
or Database_Exception [ 126 ]: Incorrect key file for table '/ramdisk/mysql/tmp/#sql_138c_2.MYI'; try to repair it [ SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `tabe` ]

So, when on your server there is no space for mysl storage files you get thta error "Error reading session data" 
The solution is make some space on server. In my case I just delete few very old files and some log files.